# Why is AngularJS service re-initialized when route is re-loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An AngularJS service is injected into two separate modules.  This is causing the service to re-initialize separately when the second module calls it. I have used the FireFox debugger to confirm that the module is being re-initialized. How can I avoid this problem?

Here is the specific case:

An AngularJS app uses an authentication service in a module called `auth` to manage authentication concerns.  The `auth` service is imported into a `message` module which manages access to the secure `/message` route and `auth` is also imported into a `navigation` module which manages both login/registration and also the visible contents of the navigation links in the user's browser.  A user is able to successfully login using the GUI tools linked to the `navigation` module, and is then successfully redirected to the secure `/message` route as an authenticated user because the `auth.authenticated1` and `auth.authenticated2` properties are set to `true` just before the redirect to `/message` occurs.

However, the FireFox debugger confirms that the problem is that, when the user refreshes the browser to reload the `/message` url pattern, the `auth` module is re-initialized, setting the values of `auth.authenticated1` and `auth.authenticated2` back to false, and thus giving the user a message that they are not logged in, even though they were logged in a moment before using valid credentials provided by the user.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the user is NOT logged out on page re-load?**

**I want the AngularJS code to check the pre-existing value for `auth.authenticated2` when the `/message` route is loaded or reloaded.**  If `auth.authenticated2=false`, then the user gets a message saying they are logged out.  But if `auth.authenticated2=true`, I want the user to be able to see the secure content at the `/message` route.  **I DO NOT want `auth.authenticated2` to be automatically re-set to `false` upon reloading the route, the way it is now.**

Here is the code in `message.html` which contains the GUI elements for the `/message` route:

```
<div ng-show="authenticated2()">
    <h1>Secure Content</h1>
    <div>
        <p>Secure content served up from the server using REST apis for authenticated users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="!authenticated2()">
    <h1>You are not logged in.</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the code in `message.js` which is the controller for the `message` module that manages the `/message` route:

```
angular.module('message', ['auth']).controller('message', function($scope, $http, $sce, auth) {

    $scope.authenticated2 = function() {
        return auth.authenticated2;
    }

    //Other code calling REST apis from the server omitted here to stay on topic

});
```

Here is the code for the `navigation` module, which also injects the `auth` service:

```
angular.module('navigation', ['ngRoute', 'auth']).controller('navigation', function($scope, $route, auth, $http, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.credentials = {};//from old navigation module
    $scope.leadresult = "blank";
    $scope.processStep = "start";
    $scope.uname = "blank";
    $scope.wleadid = "initial blank value";
    $scope.existing = "blank";

    $scope.tab = function(route) {
        return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
    };

    $scope.authenticated1 = function() {
        return auth.authenticated1;
    }

    $scope.authenticated2 = function() {
        return auth.authenticated2;
    }

    $scope.login = function() {
        auth.authenticate1($scope.credentials, function(authenticated1) {
            //a bunch of stuff that does level 1 authentication, which is not relevant here
        })
    }

    $scope.logout = auth.clear;

    //some other methods to manage registration forms in a user registration process, which are omitted here because they are off-topic

    $scope.pinForm = function(isValid) {//this method finishes authentication of user at login
        if (isValid) {
            $scope.resultmessage.webleadid = $scope.wleadid;
            $scope.resultmessage.name = $scope.uname;
            $scope.resultmessage.existing = $scope.existing;
            var funcJSON = $scope.resultmessage;        
            auth.authenticate2(funcJSON, function(authenticated2) {
                if (authenticated2) {
                    $location.path('/message');
                    $scope.$apply();//this line successfully re-directs user to `/message` route LOGGED IN with valid credentials
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        //method that makes an unrelated call to a REST service for ANONYMOUS users
    });

});
```

Here is the code for the `auth` service in `auth.js`:

```
angular.module('auth', []).factory( 'auth', function($rootScope, $http, $location) {

    var auth = {

        authenticated1 : false,
        authenticated2 : false,
        usrname : '',

        loginPath : '/login',
        logoutPath : '/logout',
        homePath : '/message',
        path : $location.path(),

        authenticate1 : function(credentials, callback) {
            var headers = credentials && credentials.username ? {
                authorization : "Basic " + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
            } : {};

            $http.get('user', {
                headers : headers
            }).success(function(data) {
                if (data.name) { auth.authenticated1 = true; } 
                else { auth.authenticated1 = false; }
                callback && callback(auth.authenticated1);
            }).error(function() {
                auth.authenticated1 = false;
                callback && callback(false);
            });
        },

        authenticate2 : function(funcJSON, callback) {
            $http.post('/check-pin', funcJSON).then(function(response) {
                if(response.data.content=='pinsuccess'){
                    auth.authenticated2=true;
                    callback && callback(auth.authenticated2);
                }else {
                    auth.authenticated2=false;
                    auth.authenticated2 = false;
                    callback && callback(false);
                }
            });
        },

        clear : function() {
            $location.path(auth.loginPath);
            auth.authenticated1 = false;
            auth.authenticated2 = false;
            $http.post(auth.logoutPath, {}).success(function() { console.log("Logout succeeded");
            }).error(function(data) { console.log("Logout failed"); });
        },

        init : function(homePath, loginPath, logoutPath) {
            auth.homePath = homePath;
            auth.loginPath = loginPath;
            auth.logoutPath = logoutPath;
        }
    };
    return auth;
});
```

The `routeProvider` is managed by the main `js` file for the app, which is `hello.js` and is as follows:

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute', 'auth', 'home', 'message', 'public1', 'navigation' ])
    .config(

        function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);/* This line is one of 3 places where we set natural urls to remote the default # */

            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'js/home/home.html',
                controller : 'home'
            }).when('/message', {
                templateUrl : 'js/message/message.html',
                controller : 'message'
            }).when('/public1', {
                templateUrl : 'js/public1/public1.html',
                controller : 'public1'
            }).when('/register', {
                templateUrl : 'js/navigation/register.html',
                controller : 'navigation'
            }).otherwise('/');

            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

        }).run(function(auth) {

            // Initialize auth module with the home page and login/logout path
            // respectively
            auth.init('/checkpin', '/login', '/logout');

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer as in, exact code to change here. But enough to get something built nicely.

You shouldn't explicitly use only boolean values inside your auth service. As far as I can see, you're not using any data that you're receiving from the server after a successful authentication. So whenever you refresh, everything is lost. You don't have anything in your code to recover from a refresh.

Ideally, you should have something like a token or a cookie. The cookie will be saved and can be recovered after a refresh, so while starting the auth service, you can check for the existence of that cookie.

You could also save a token that can be used to access an API inside an indexedDB or something like that. Just as I said before, during boot time of the auth service, you'll have to check for the existence of that token.

If you need more information, check for Oauth2. Even though Oauth2 isn't an Authentication API but an authorization API, the password grant type is something you could use. To get an idea how to build a solid system. The other grant types are mostly only focused on the authorization side of OAuth.

Because OP ask for code here it is:

```
when creating_service:
  if exists(cookie) or exists(token) and valid(cookie) or valid(token):
     mark_service_as_logged_in()
```

If pseudo code is better than words.

Comment: @CodeMed what you're asking is for him to write an authentication system for you. It's no small task. It's completely tied to your server. You might consider doing some more research into cookies/authentication tokens and then asking a much more narrower question when you get stuck.

Comment: wow... `Please show code. The OP asks for code` hope you're kidding right?

Comment: The cookie has to be done on the server side. I'm sorry but you're asking for a theoritical answer as You don't seem to have any idea how authentication works.

Comment: This user's response did not begin to address the question stated in the OP.

Comment: The OP clearly specifies:  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the user is NOT logged out on page re-load?**

Comment: Ok, First, you don't pay me to write code so don't ask for code. Most of the work has to be done on the server side not in Angular. What I wrote you is better than code because it explain the problem and how to fix it without being specific to an implementation. It will work for Angular or any framework or even without anything. If the answer doesn't answer the question what does it answer then? If you want to roll your own authentication, don't ask for anybody to do it for you. I'm sure that if you read about oauth and cookies you'd already solved your answer.