# How do I manage cookie values in AngularJS service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

An AngularJS service receives a cookie from calls to a backend REST service.  The cookie value is used as the value of a variable, so that the value of that variable can persist across repeated re-initializations of the service by other modules in the AngularJS app, as long as the REST service is not called again to change the value of the cookie.  I read the documentation [at this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies), but the documentation does not include a method for CHANGING the value of an existing cookie.  The documentation also does not comment on initializing the value of a cookie-derived variable in a service module.

**How do I modify the code below to manage changes in the value of the cookie throughout the service's life cycle, so that changes are made when the backend REST calls dictate it, but so that the value of the cookie otherwise persists after the AngularJS service is re-initialized?**

Here is the code that I have developed so far:

The cookie is generated on a backend server by a Spring RestController, and is sent with the response as follows:

```
response.addCookie(new Cookie("keyName", "oneValue"));
```

(The Response from the server also includes a JSON object, which you see in the `http.post(..` below.

In the client AngularJS app, the variable is declared and populated with the value of the cookie at the top of the AngularJS module's code as follows:

```
someVariable : cookies.get('keyName'),
```

And then the value of the cookie is either populated or changed at two different points in a method of the module, depending on the results of the attempted call to the backend as follows:

```
someModule.someVariable = $cookies.put('keyName', 'oneValue');

else:  

someModule.someVariable = $cookies.put('keyName', 'anotherValue');
```

The entire code for the module is as follows:

```
angular.module('someModule', ['ngCookies']).factory( 'someModule', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {

    var someModule = {

        someVariable : cookies.get('keyName'),//populate variable

        someMethod : function(funcJSON, callback) {
            $http.post('/rest-service-url', funcJSON).then(function(response, $cookies) {
                if(response.data.content=='whatweexpect'){
                    someModule.someVariable = $cookies.put('keyName', 'oneValue');//DOES THIS CHANGE VALUE OF COOKIE?
                    callback && callback(someModule.someVariable);
                }else {
                    someModule.someVariable = $cookies.put('keyName', 'anotherValue');//DOES THIS CHANGE VALUE OF COOKIE?
                    callback && callback(false);
                }
             });
        },

        init : function() {
            //some unrelated stuff
        }
    };
    return someModule;
});
```

The value of the cookie is then used by `ng-show` to determine what gets shown to a user in views, as follows:

```
<div ng-show="someVariable=='oneValue'">
    <p>oneValue says we give this content.</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="someVariable=='anotherValue'">
    <h1>anotherValue says we give this other content.</h1>
</div>
<div ng-show="someVariable==null">
    <h1>Assume the backend REST service has never been called, so give default content.</h1>
</div>
```

**What specific changes do I make to the above code in order to manage the value of the cookie through all the changes from initialization, repeated calls to the backend REST service, and repeated re-initializations?**

Comment: The line `$http.post('/rest-service-url', funcJSON).then(function(response, $cookies) {` should not need $cookie as an argument to the function as $http service does not return a cookie. If you `console.log` it, I assume it will be another object or undefined.

Comment: @ryan0319 Thank you for looking closely.  This is partly pseudo code to make it clearer in an SO post.  I added a line at the top of the post showing how the cookie is created in the Spring REST controller and attached to the `response`.  The REST service sends a JSON object and a cookie in `response`.  Thus the `http.post(...` in the AngularJS code needs to process both the JSON and the cookie.  The JSON is handled perfectly, but I do not know how to handle the cookie.  Does this help isolate the problem?

Comment: [That the value of that variable can persist across repeated re-initializations of the service by other modules in the AngularJS app]. I didn't understand that ? A service is initialized only once by angular. only a page reload would make it reinitialize. So i don't understand the need of the cookie.

Comment: @Walfrat My authorization service re-initializes the value of boolean properties whenever a user re-loads a secured route.  So the user successfully authenticates and is redirected to the secure page and sees secure content.  But then the user re-loads the secure route in the browser and the values are re-set to false so the user gets logged out.  Another user suggested a cookie based approach, so I am making this post.  Here is the other link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846833/why-is-angularjs-service-re-initialized-when-route-is-re-loaded